# Multiple websites pointing to the same directory rewrite url to point different folders

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have 3+ websites, example:

```
www.example.com/requestedpage
www.esempio.it/requestedpage
primer.ru/requestedpage
```

All websites points to the same server's directory. There are 3 directories in it: "en", "it", "ru" with localized requestedpage in them. I want to internally redirect those requests (only PHP, not images) to folders without changing URL. So .com website read pages from "en" folder it - "it", ru - "ru" folder but user shouldn't see that.

I tried some things but they doesn't work..

```
RewriteCond ^(.+)\.(ru)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/ru/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.(ru)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ ru%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} MYWEBSITE.ru$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !ru/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ru/$1 [NC,L]
```

After a lot of tests and thanks to anubhava help I found a way to deal with it, not nice way, and I think it should be improved:

```
# ===== MULTILANGUAGE WEBSITES =====
#Rule for IT website
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !ITALIANDOMAIN\.it$
RewriteRule .* - [S=3]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ it/$1/$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ it/$1
RewriteRule ^$ it/ [NC,L]

#Rule for FR website
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !FRANCEDOMAIN\.com$
RewriteRule .* - [S=3]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ fr/$1/$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ fr/$1
RewriteRule ^$ fr/ [NC,L]

#Rule for RU website
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(RUSSIANDOMAIN1\.com)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(xn--10-olc1a0ag\.xn--p1ai)$
RewriteRule .* - [S=3]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ ru/$1/$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ ru/$1
RewriteRule ^$ ru/ [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule from a .htaccess placed inside the parent folder of of `it, en, ru` folders:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip all files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.(ru|it)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:ru|it)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ %1/$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ en/$0 [L]
```

Comment: The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. I'll try more tomorrow, but removing all my rules and adding just those it doesn't work

Comment: wow, almost. It works fine for all requests except requests which has / it them, like: www.example.com/folder/page is it possible to redirect the whole request to a folder "en" in this case? :)

Comment: I was trying this one (good for tester) but doesn't work on server: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.it$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ it/$0 [NC,L]

Comment: Oh finally found a way to redirect: file, folder/file, index page, here is it for it domain:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.it$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ it/$1/$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ it/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^$ it/ [NC,L]
I'll just copy&paste it changing domain because I don't know how to work with "or" and use it as parameter

Comment: Update: ah no, I have multiple condition and rules, it doesn't work in this manner

Comment: if file (like images) exists it should ignore that rule, finally I have created a rule for me, it is very long and complicated but it works (I've update the question). Oh, it's not nice but works. I'll try to start from your last answer to find a better way now

Comment: Almost perfect, it doesn't work for index page: www.domain.ru/ If I remove a rule that redirect index.php page (it's not nice to have it in the url) - it works as www.domain.ru/index.php but as www.domain.ru/ it doesn't work. P.S. removing [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d it works, will perform more tests now